# Filezilla logs shows non-transfers

Tags: filezilla

When I use "Overwrite files if newer" the log shows all the hundreds of files in the DIRs I am "uploading", but there may be only a few files actually uploaded (the newer ones)

Is there a way to filter the log so it only shows files that have actually been uploaded?

Edit :

The "Successful Transfers" panel shows all files in the directory structure selected for upload. But if "Overwrite files if newer" is on, you will still get all the files that were not actually transferred. This is a problem when hundreds of files are selected and only a few are newer, no way to tell what actually updated.

For example only chat_send.php was actually uploaded in the following images:

[image: transfer panel]

The "Message Log" panel will tell you what got uploaded if you have the detailed mode on. But if you have thousands of lines in the log it is a real pain to find what got transferred.

[image: message log]

Comment: Consider adding an example small portion of your log with an [edit] and be sure to show an example that show what you do not want to be displayed and another that shows what you'd wish to be displayed only. Also you should include what operating system you are using to review these logs (i.e. Windows, Linux, etc.).

Comment: This is a very important missed feature. My project has more than 900 files and I develop on the local machine and upload the entire project 1 or 2 times daily. However only the modified files are actually transferred and I really really need to see which files are actually transferred among the entire project :( I hope FileZilla developers change [their mind](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjLzMSj1azcAhWEaFAKHSq4AlIQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.filezilla-project.org%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ft%3D20939&usg=AOvVaw3zQbAJr9iT8PCWz_oO_G9E) about this feature.